# What's the relationship between persons non-symmetrically addressing each other as first-name and Mr. Smith?

Tags: interpersonal-relations

What's the exact relationship between two **adult** people which call each other non-symmetrically, one by first name and other by Mr. Smith?

Many languages have this distinction and I believe the use cases for such asymmetrical addressing are not the same. So I'm asking about this in English.

Is it demeaning for the one who is called by one's first name? Do they feel it unpleasant? **Is it a sign of patronizing?**

Is it perceived as demeaning if a doctor calls an adult patient *John* but is called himself *Dr. Smith*? (In my language it would be terribly patronizing and demeaning.)

Has it changed over time? In Jane Austen's there are lots of such examples, such as Emma and Mr. Knightly.

Is this perceived the same in UK, USA, Australia, and Canada?

Comment: It's usually a difference in status. In a business setting, superiors may be addressed more formally than underlings. Children usually call adults by their formal name, adults address children by first name. Patients call doctors "Dr. Smith", but the doctor might call the patient by their first name.

Comment: The relationship could be anything.  It is more likely that some local, cultural conventions would apply, depending on where the people are located, than it is that some conventional relationship holds generally. IOW, you should **not** assume a difference of age or status or gender or... You are better off, if you are unaware of any local cultural conventions, assuming that this behavior is specific to the two particular people: their personal history led to it.

Comment: It can also be personal preference. Watch the US TV program "Person of Interest". Finch refers to all his cohorts as "Mr." or "Ms", it seems like it's just the way he was raised.

Comment: I agree entirely with Drew, at least in the US.  Addressing is not a reliable indicator of anything in and of itself.

Comment: Sales and customer support staff from some companies regularly address their customers by first name: I believe this is deliberate policy to try to create a friendly relationship. For me (and, I suspect, for many older people) it does the reverse: it comes over to me as false, rude, and intrusive.

Comment: @Colin I feel similarly, except that to me, it's the fact that they use your name at all, given or sur, that comes off as false. Normal people don't say the names of the people they're talking to all the time.

Comment: Conventions in this area have been changing very rapidly in many Western countries in the past few decades. Society-wide discomfort with explicit class-based distinctions (especially in Scandinavia) has led to the near-abandonment of titles of deference in many countries, especially among younger folk. In Denmark, for instance, children will call their teachers by their first names. Paradoxically, it is in many quarters of the USA's supposed 'classless society' that deferential modes of address cling on most firmly. Even its criminals are routinely described as 'gentlemen' by police officers.

Comment: Get this: 30 years ago I worked with a Swedish lawyer in Paris. She was written up in the local Swedosj paper and they put her first name only in the title for the article. So....

Answer (score 1):

What is in the background of this question, and is hinted at by the OP's writing *adult* in bold, is that the use of such asymmetrical forms of address is fairly common between children and adults (other than immediate family members). The practice may not be as widespread now as it was in the past, in that many adults in English-speaking countries now permit, or even encourage, the children they interact with to address them less formally, but it is still the default: children need the adult's permission to use a less formal form of address, while the adults don't need the child's permission to address the child by the first name or even nickname. Of course, like all such social norms, this one is not very precise: there is no sharp definition of an adult, or a child, or a family member that one can rely on in applying it.

Because this asymmetry characterises the relationships between adults and children, it **can** be perceived as patronising between two adults. This is so, even if the adults are of unequal social status: bosses who treat their subordinates respectfully will either address them with their titles and surnames, or they will foster a generally informal atmosphere in the workplace by encouraging the subordinates to address them by their first names as well.

Between two people of equal status, the use of asymmetrical forms of address is rare, because one person's addressing the other informally will usually be interpreted as an invitation to the other that such informal forms be used both ways. What is patronising about a boss addressing a subordinate by the first name (and not inviting the subordinate to reciprocate) is not so much the form of address itself, but the expectation that the subordinate will not dare to reciprocate.

It should, however, be noted that the increasing general informality in English-speaking societies may mean that an average person in such a society is generally less sensitive to how they are addressed than typical members of many other societies. I suspect that average contemporary English speakers (particularly the younger ones) are not greatly bothered by the asymmetrical forms of address when they encounter them in real life, even  if they would, upon reflection, say that they are patronising.

There are also a couple of **exceptions** to the generally patronising character of such asymmetry. First, sometimes one person starts addressing the other by the first name with good faith expectation that the other person would reciprocate, but the other person finds it uncomfortable to do so (perhaps because the habits of traditional etiquette are too deeply engrained in the person). The asymmetry may persist in such a case, without either of them patronising the other. Second, one may sometimes be dealing at the same time with a number of people with the same surname and the title; in such a case the use of first names is a way of avoiding possible confusion as to who is being addressed.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is a *relationship between unequals*.

In the US and Canada, it's fairly common for one to address his employer or supervisor by the more formal title and surname.  In the 1950s, children were taught to address adults, except within the family, by their title and surname; that is less common now.

As students become adolescents and adults, their instructors may address the student by their personal name, their surname, or their title plus surname.

Waitresses in truck stops call their customers "Dearie", or 'Sweetie" or "Honey", expecting to get larger tips and an occasional pat on the butt. Nurses and aides use the same patronizing terms for geriatric patients, who quickly learn not to complain about it.

Clients generally refer to "Doctor Marcus" or 'Doctor Welby" as staff members do, with the use of the personal name being more casual, and the use of the surname being more respectful. It seems to me that the less competent a professional is, the more likely he is to be "Mr. Accountant" rather than "Jim".

In the military, soldiers are be supposed to be called by their surname without a title, and as they achieve promotion, are most likely to be addressed by their rank (for instance "gunny", "sarge" or "sergeant major"), although nicknames ("Jonesy! Nashville! Police the  area!") are sometimes used. Officers are addressed by rank and title, or by rank alone.

Comment: "Rank and title" or "Rank and name"?

Comment: @Honza Zidek -  There is also the southern US usage which is still very much in vogue down here. Say your boss is named Jim Smith. Instead of addressing him Mr.Smith, you can say "Mr. Jim." Though this is considered very nice and polite, it bears an awful legacy which most of us are unaware of: slavery.  The house servants would not address their masters by last name - it just seemed too weird even then to address someone with their last name when you were around them all day. So Mr., Mrs., or, Miss First_name resulted.

Comment: Most of this answer is about the forms of address that are used in English **generally**, rather than the **specific** practice of **asymmetric** forms of address being used between two people.

Comment: I think most American corporations use first names throughout the structure (certainly in more progressive industries like IT and media).

Answer (score 0):

While your question has English example, a similar situation also happens in Japan.

Basically speaking, in Japan first names are reserved for close friends and families, acquaintances should always use family names, breach of this rule is considered extremely rude.

In the West, your example is generally as Deke Thomas said (and is similar to Japanese usage): calling people by first name implies close relationship, calling them by family name is formal usage for formal occassions

Comment: While this may be generally true, it does not address the OP's specific question about **asymmetric** forms of address being used between two people.